# Scala iterate over a map represented by a board

Tags: list, scala, dictionary

I've made a function that will parse a string that is 81 characters long. While parsing it, I need to use a function called `neighbors(Int: row, Int: col)` that returns all the coordinates that are vertical, horizontal, and diagonal from the specified row and col. With this list of coordinates, I need to remove the value I placed from each of the possible values listed at each coordinate. The board is represented as a map, and I need to do this functionally, i.e. without using var.

Here's my parse function:

```
str.zipWithIndex.map{
    case (digit, index) => ((index / 9, index % 9), List(digit.asDigit))
  }.toMap
```

Here's what I know about the `neighbors` function:

```
def neighbors(row: Int, col: Int): List[(Int, Int)]
```

For example, if the parser was on the coordinate `(0,2)`, and the number entered into the map was `4`, I would have to remove `4` from all the coordinates vertical, horizontal, and diagonal from that point. Each point's value is represented as a list of possible values.

I also am not given the implementation of the `neighbor` function.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: 1st - I thought [Karl's suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36266982/scala-returning-coordinate-as-tuple) was a much better design for your parser.  2nd - It's hard to suggest how to use the `neighbor` function without seeing its exact signature, or at least its return data type. 3rd - You can't remove anything from coordinates that haven't been populated yet, so it would seem, from your description, that `neighbor` would have to be called on each element after `parse` is finished.

Comment: I agree, Karl's suggestion was great. I figured out how to have empty cells be populated with a list. When I posted this question, I hadn't figured it out yet. I'll update the question. Also, I'll add the signature of the `neighbor` function. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, it's about how to mutate things (in this case remove from the `Map`) while staying functional?

If yes, there are two approaches:

1. Create tail recursive function that is called for each iteration with the list of remaining elements to process and current state of your "mutable" data:

   ```
   @tailrec
   def process(
        input: List[(Char, Int)],
        board: Map[Any, Any],
        resultAccum: List[Result]): List[Result] = input match {
     case Nil => resultAccum.reverse
     case (char, pos) :: tail =>
       // do the processing
       val updatedBoard = board - ??? // create update version of the board
       val updateResults = ??? :: resultAccum
       process(tail, updatedBoard, updateResults)
   }
   ```
2. Or you can use `foldLeft`, that does that same, but looks shorter:

   ```
   input.foldLeft((initialBoard, List[Result]())) {
     case ((board, resultsAccum), (char, pos)) =>
       val updatedBoard = board - ??? // create update version of the board
       val updateResults = ??? :: resultsAccum
       (updatedBoard, updateResults)
   }._2.reverse
   ```

   Initial state of the `foldLeft` contains initial state of the board and empty list of results.